# Formatting the time selector form properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, datetime, time

In simple form the following time selector is giving me a formate of  HHam/pm:MM. Tried multiple things to get it to HH:MMam/pm to no avail. Any idea how to change this?

```
<%= f.input :end_time, as: :time, ampm: true %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Can be achieved by using **strftime**

create a method in the Application Helper as

```
def time_format(datetime)
  datetime.strftime('%H:%M:%p') unless datetime.blank?
end
```

And then on the form:

```
<%= f.input_field :end_time, :as => :string, :value => time_format(f.object.end_time) %>
```

Comment: So this requires the user to enter an end_date as a string instead of using a drop down selector, correct? At least that is what shows in my browser.